# Suggestions required to improve my first use of Rails Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a task in my Rails app that can update a gallery album. This is passed an id that corresponds with an album on my Flickr account, it deletes all the photos attached to the album locally in the app and pulls them afresh from Flickr and updates the album name and title if required. This is required because I am currently working my way through all my photos re-tagging them all and this task will help pull those tags from Flickr to my site for searching and linking purposes.

I built an admin page that lists all my albums and each has an "Update Album" button.  That looks like:

gallery.html.erb

```
<table class="striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Collections</th>
          <th>Albums</th>
          <th>Photo count</th>
          <th>Flickr ID</th>
          <th>Options</th>
        </tr>

        <% @collections.each do |c| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= c.title %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><%= c.flickr_id %></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <% if c.has_albums? %>
            <% c.albums.each do |a| %>
              <tr class="<%= a.title.parameterize %>">
                <td>&#x21B3;</td>
                <td>
                  <%= a.title %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <%= a.photos.count %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <%= a.flickr_id %>
                </td>
                <td class="this-one">
                  <%= link_to "Update",
                    admin_update_album_path(
                      album_flickr_id:a.flickr_id,
                      row: a.title.parameterize
                    ),
                    "am-button": '',
                    method: :post,
                    remote: true
                  %>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </table>
```

Because the task of updating took a while I thought putting it as a background job would be a good idea. Here's my controller and job:

gallery_controller.rb
    class Admin::GalleryController < AdminController

```
  def update_album
    UpdateAlbumJob.perform_later(params[:album_flickr_id], params[:row])
  end

end
```

update_album_job.rb

```
class UpdateAlbumJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  after_perform do |job|
    album = Album.find_by(flickr_id: job.arguments.first)
    album.update_attribute(:updating, false)
    puts job.arguments
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'album_updates_channel', content: 'Update complete', row: job.arguments[1], status: 'complete'
  end

  def perform(album_flickr_id, row)
    require 'flickraw'

    FlickRaw.api_key=ENV["FLICKR_API_KEY"]
    FlickRaw.shared_secret=ENV["FLICKR_API_SECRET"]
    flickr.access_token=ENV["FLICKR_OAUTH_TOKEN"]
    flickr.access_secret=ENV["FLICKR_OAUTH_SECRET"]

    # album_flickr_id = params[:album_flickr_id] or raise "No Album Flickr ID specified"
    album = Album.find_by(flickr_id: album_flickr_id)

    album.update_attribute(:updating, true)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'album_updates_channel', content: 'Updating&hellip;', row: row, status: 'in-progress'

    # Album.find_by(flickr_id: album_flickr_id).destroy if Album.find_by(flickr_id: album_flickr_id)

    # Get tags
    @flickr_tags_list = flickr.tags.getListUserRaw user_id: ENV["FLICKR_USER_ID"]
    @tags_key = {}

    @flickr_tags_list['tags'].each do |t|
      @tags_key[t['clean'].to_sym] = t['raw'].first
    end
    # ========

    # Work out parent collection
    # This needs to cater for when there is NO parent collection
    @collections = flickr.collections.getTree user_id: ENV["FLICKR_USER_ID"]
    @parent_id = nil

    def search_for_set_id_of_collection(set_id, collection, empty)
      if collection["collection"]
        collection.collection.each_with_index do |c|
          search_for_set_id_of_collection(set_id, c, @parent_id)
        end
      end

      if collection["set"]
        collection["set"].each do |set|
          if set["id"] == set_id
            @parent_id = collection["id"]
          end
        end
      end
    end

    @collections.each do |c|
      search_for_set_id_of_collection(album_flickr_id, c, @parent_id)
    end
    # ========

    Photo.where(album_id: album.id).destroy_all

    Album.add_set_from_flickr(album_flickr_id, @parent_id, ENV["FLICKR_USER_ID"], @tags_key, true)
  end
end
```

albumupdates.js:

```
const ActionCable = require('actioncable-modules');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const actionCable = ActionCable.createConsumer(process.env.WEBSOCKET_SERVER)

actionCable.subscriptions.create("AlbumUpdatesChannel", {
  received: function(data) {
    console.log('Hello from Action Cable');

    if (data.status == 'in-progress') {
      $('.' + data['row'] + ' td.this-one [am-Button]').hide();
      $('.' + data['row'] + ' td.this-one').append(data['content']);
    } else {
      $('.' + data['row'] + ' td.this-one [am-Button]').show();
      $('.' + data['row'] + ' td.this-one p').hide();
    }
  }
})
```

Basically, this is the first time i've just background jobs and action cable.  I'm not 100% sure whether i've done this correctly but i wanted to give them a try and then ask on here for comments and suggestions.  It sort of works ok but I have some questions:

1. Is this the best way of updating the table of albums with the status of the job? eg, "Updating..." and "Update complete!".   I'd love to show an "Update Complete!" message but somehow remove that once it's been seen so just the button is showing again but unsure what path to go down to achieve that.
2. How would the live page updates work if i start an album updating, go away from the page and come back?
3. Also i'm unsure if my `albumupdates.js` file is set up correctly?

Just some comments and improvements to my code would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Few hints : 2 - you have to give a unique ID to the container div that will hold data coming from the background job  / albumuodates.js . Then actionable will broadcast to this very id. If you are on a different page then the js won't update anything. 3- I don't understand why you have an in-progress section as you will broadcast after the job is complete only.

Comment: Check Stackoverflow guidelines, you have to use a title that describes your problem, if you can't come up with one maybe you are asking too many questions at once.

Comment: @arieljuod Title updated.

Comment: @Maxence When you say to the container div.  You mean each row of the table? I did add a unique class to each row and I pass that into the job so it knows which row to update on return?  Also which bit is incorrect for in-progress?

Comment: Sorry my mistake I didn't notice the first ActionCable broadcast to add temporary information for the user. So everything looks fine to me. And if it works well I would say it's all good.